# Running into AWS Elastic BeanStalk Event Error: Manifest file has schema validation errors

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am setting up pipelines to AWS Elastic BeanStalk via bitbucket and I am running into: Manifest file has schema validation errors: Error Kind: ArrayItemNotValid, Path: #/aspNetCoreWeb.[0], Property: [0] Error Kind: PropertyRequired, Path: #/parameters.appBundle, Property: appBundle Error Kind: NoAdditionalPropertiesAllowed, Path: #/parameters, Property: parameters.

It seems that I am have a problem with my manifest file. However due to there being very little documentation on how to fix this problem. I am not able to resolve this issue. How do I solve this problem?

Here is my aws-windows-deployment-manifest file:

```
{
  "manifestVersion": 1,
  "deployments": {
    "aspNetCoreWeb": [
      {
        "name": "CareerDash",
        "parameters": {
          "archive": "site",
          "iisPath": "/"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look like I figured it out. The issue is that the aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json file should be like the following:

```
{
  "manifestVersion": 1,
  "deployments": {
    "aspNetCoreWeb": [
      {
        "name": "CareerDash",
        "parameters": {
          "appBundle": "site.zip", /*This line is where your web app file location is. The Web app folder should be in .zip file. */
          "iisPath": "/" /* This line is the path to where your web app files are located in site.zip file, specifically the path to web.config file (which should be in the same level as your main web app files */
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Overall your app bundle should be a zip file that contains the site.zip file and aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json file. In a hierarchy like so:

appBundleName.zip

- site.zip
- aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json